# CTE - Reverse Hierarchy

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need to generate bread crumb like path of groups of a **particular contact**.

T_GROUP stores actual hierarchy of groups:

```
GROUP_ID    NAME            PARENT_ID   LEVEL
    7      g1              NULL         1
    80    Workgroups      7            2
    82    Advocacy        80           3
```

T_CONTACT_GROUP table stores groups belonging to contacts:

```
CONTACT_ID  GROUP_ID 
55          82
56            7
55            7
```

Now, I would like to get result set as following **for contact Id 55**: Please note that g1 has come twice in expected result set as contact 55 has been assigned group 7 also.

```
contactId GROUP_ID NAME PARENT_ID   LEVEL
55        7     g1      NULL        1
55        80       g1|Workgroups 7 2
55       82        g1|Workgroups|Advocacy 80 3
55       7         g1 NULL 1
```

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two ways to do this.
You mention CTE in your title, so I'll go with that first.
From the link [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2007/10/17/hierarchies-with-common-table-expressions.aspx) I have an example of a hiererchical CTE, a little massage and it will represent the parents rather than children:

```
WITH Hierarchy (Group_ID, Name, Parent_ID, Level) AS
(
    SELECT Group_ID, Name, Parent_ID, Level
    FROM T_Group
    WHERE Contact_id = @Leaf
UNION ALL 
    SELECT g.Group_ID, g.Name, g.Parent_ID, g.Level
    FROM T_Group g
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy h ON g.Group_ID = h.Parent
)
```

This CTE would be placed in a stored procedure or table User Defined Function, taking a parameter of @Leaf (the leaf node for which your looking. In your example it's 82 and then 7).

The problem with this is that hierarchical CTEs can be very expensive, expecially if working on deeper tree structures or called repetitively. Caching can help, but there are other options.

Another way is to store the hierarchy of parents in a string concatenated field alongside your groups:

```
GROUP_ID NAME      PARENT_ID LEVEL PARENTS
82        Advocacy 80        3     |7|80|82|
```

You could then do something like:

```
SELECT p.Group_ID, g.Name, g.Parent_ID, g.Level
FROM T_GROUP g
CROSS JOIN dbo.StringSplit('|', Parents) p
WHERE p.Value = g.Group_ID
```

to get all the details of the parents. This tends to be much more efficient than using a CTE to handle to lookup. It does mean that when you insert new records into GROUP that you must build the parent field too. Usually to handle this you would create a Stored Procedure that created the Group for you, building the Parents as required.